# 404 error for page view event, google tag manager or application?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

[image]

When i check console in Chrome DevTools i see the 404 error above.  Pasted example below:

`POST https://www.example.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-XXXXXX&gtm=2oe8b0&_p=424137054&sr=1366x768&ul=en-us&cid=1940949659.1614938183&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fmovies%2F&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fcasts%2F&dt=Movies%20Free&sid=1628778501&sct=16&seg=1&en=page_view 404`

I don't know where to start debugging, is this a google tag manager or google analytics error?  Every time a page on website is viewed, this error is displayed in console.  The route "/g/collect" doesn't exist on my application.  How do i solve? Do i have to create the route on my application or change something in tag manager?

Answer (score 2):

The path is from a tracking call to GA4 (recognizable by the `/g/collect` route and the `v=2` parameter, which refers to measurement protocol version 2).

If that is actually your own domain in that request, then it is possible that somebody has changed the "transport_url" property in the GA4 configuration in the "Fields to set" section of the GA4 configuration tag.

Or somebody set the "Send to Server Container" option and added your domain, which is essentially a nicer UI for the same feature.

If you have not configured the route on your server, this will result in a 404. You would configure this only if you run a proxy for you GA4 calls or want to use server-side Google Tag Manager. If you do not want to do that, just remove the setting.

Answer (score 2):

For client-side GA, the endpoint should be: https://**analytics.google.com**/g/collect

For example:

```
https://analytics.google.com/g/collectv=2&tid=G-XXXXXX&gtm=2oe8b0&_p=424137054&sr=1366x768&ul=en-us&cid=1940949659.1614938183&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fmovies%2F&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fcasts%2F&dt=Movies%20Free&sid=1628778501&sct=16&seg=1&en=page_view
```

Are you sending to https://www.example.com/g/collect or was this used for demonstration purposes?

The only time that endpoint would be different for any GA property is if you're sending data to a Server-Side GTM container.

Comment: Developer set up Server-Side GTM Container to use Facebook Conversion API.  What should be the correct endpoint for the container?  Any examples?

Comment: That would depend on the server setup. Usually this has an A/AAAA name record for a subdomain to your own domain (so requests from your server-side installation can set first party cookies). If you do not have a subdomain configured, the server-side containers are by default hosted on an appspot-domain  (something like "https://gtm-txdwpqg8-otrhm.uc.r.appspot.com/").

Comment: You can find your current endpoint if you login to your server-side GTM container and go to: Admin > Container Settings. You'll see it under "Server container URL".